# windows os shut down eventhandler

Tags: windows, windows-vista, shutdown

Is there anyway to handle windows os shutdown, and cancel shutting down?

I want to cancel shut down which's processed by user( **a planned shut down**).

**SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OTHER | SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_OTHER | SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED**

I look kernel32.dll, but I could not find anything about that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is still supported but if an application returns 0 in response to a WM_QUERYENDSESSION message, the system will not shut down.